# Word for either indoors or outdoors

Tags: single-word-requests

A phrase that kind of illustrates what I'm looking for is something like "Activity Type".

Activity Type: indoor

Activity Type: outdoor

Is there a single word that can better represent the concept of either indoors or outdoors?

Some words I've thought of are "venue", "location" and  "place", but these are all a bit too general.

Comment: For a field on a form or whatever and to indicate it's an indoor activity, I'd put, "Indoor/Outdoor: Indoor."

Comment: Could be a good option, but I may add other fields to it later. For example "mixed" for activities which are both indoor and outdoor. I think "setting" might work...

Comment: If something can be both or either, then there is an adjective: "indoor-outdoor."  The adjective "indoor-outdoor" means that it is suitable for either indoor or outdoor or both (e.g., indoor-outdoor carpeting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [**environment**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/environment):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : the circumstances, objects, or conditions by which one is surrounded

Context would make it clear what the possible choices are.

While starting with *indoor* and *outdoor*, you could add *mixed*, as you say.

But it's a lot more flexible than just that. The environment for the activity could also be something like *underwater*, if it involved swimming.